# How do I change a URL category number to a word with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, .htaccess, seo

I bought an iPhone wallpaper gallery PHP script a year ago, and it has been running great. I've been slowly learning PHP and MySQL by doing little tweaks here and there.

To view a category, the URL is `www.example.com/index.php?catid=27`, and I want to change it to `www.example.com/index.php?catid=apple` for SEO reasons. I know I can futher tidy up the URL with .htaccess but I just want to get this word slug to begin with.

This is the code (inside **index.php**) that I think generates the category pages:

```
if (($_REQUEST['catid']) && ($_REQUEST['catid'] > 1)) {
        $catid = $_REQUEST['catid'];
        if (is_numeric($catid)) {
            $tempitemarray = $myitems->getItemsByCategory($catid);
            $catnav = "&catid=" . $catid;
            $tempcat = new Category();
            $tempcat->getCategory($catid);
            $maintitle = "<h1>" . $tempcat->getCategoryName() . " " . $itemplural . "</h1>";
        }
```

That code calls another PHP page called **itemList.php**, and inside that page I found this code:

```
public function getItemsByCategory($catid) {
        $this->retrieveSQL = "select * from items i, item_category_lookup l where livedate < '" . $this->currentdate . "' and  i.active = " . $this->showApproved . " and l.categoryid = $catid and i.id = l.itemid order by i.livedate desc limit " . $this->startRow . "," . $this->numRows;
        $this->countSQL = "select * from items i, item_category_lookup l where livedate < '" . $this->currentdate . "' and  i.active = " . $this->showApproved . " and l.categoryid = $catid and i.id = l.itemid";
        $this->retrieveItems();
        return $this->items;
    }
```

This is the '**items**' table:

```
    id | itemname | itemdec | itemkeywords | createdate | viewcount | active | rating | livedate | sourcedesc | sourceurl
-----------------------------------
    64 | Apple Logo
```

This is the '**item_category_lookup**' table:

```
categoryid | itemid
-------------------------
27         | 64
```

This is the '**category**' table below. It's not called in the query above but does have the actual category names. How would I implement it?

```
id | categoryid
------------------
27 | Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You might change the SQL of `$this->retrieveSQL = ...` into

```
if (!is_number($catid)) {
        $this->retrieveSQL = "select * from items i, item_category_lookup l, category j where livedate < '" . $this->currentdate . "' and  i.active = " . $this->showApproved . " and i.id = l.itemid and j.id = l.categroyid and j.categoryid = "$catid" order by i.livedate desc limit " . $this->startRow . "," . $this->numRows;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me :(
I know I need to get rid of the `is_numeric($catid)`part because I don't want it to be accepting numbers, I want a world slug.

Comment: Until someone sets currentdate = `"01-01-1901';drop table items;--"`

Comment: @Will Can you please explain what you are talking about?

Comment: @Shaun since it is a GET Request from the URL if somebody adds this string to the URL the DB table "items" might get deleted if the MySQL user of this DB connection has rights to delete tables. This is a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
URL example: www.example.com/index.php?catid=27-apple

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['catid'] ) ) {
    $catSEO = explode( '-', $_REQUEST['catid'] );
}
$catid = is_numeric( $catSEO[0] ) ? $catSEO:0;
```

Comment: Where abouts would this go? I can show you my `index.php` and `itemList.php` files if that would help?

Comment: @Shaun put this in your index.php, this is how you get the Category ID. Just implement in your old code.
like this: 

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['catid'] ) ) {
        $catSEO = explode( '-', $_REQUEST['catid'] );
        $catid = is_numeric( $catSEO[0] ) ? $catSEO:0;
        if ( $catid ) {
            $tempitemarray = $myitems->getItemsByCategory($catid);
            $catnav = "&catid=" . $catid;
            $tempcat = new Category();
            $tempcat->getCategory($catid);
            $maintitle = "<h1>" . $tempcat->getCategoryName() . " " . $itemplural . "</h1>";
        }

Comment: I just tried your code and unfortunately it doesn't work. It just loads the latest wallpapers page which is its 'else' fallback if no catid is specified.

Comment: @Shaun this is the way to do SEO on your URL, just adapt the code for what you need. Add an `else` on your code to go back page or return a 404 page.